# Is the Intellitrace Standalone Collector capable of tracking call information?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, intellitrace

I'm seeing varying information online, some guides claim it's possible and I've found some other sources that state it's not supported due to performance issues.

I'm not using it for a web service, I have an executable that I'm trying to trace. Whenever I use the default collection plans that are provided I'm able to see event data (exceptions), but no call information such as parameter/variable values. Is this even possible with the standalone collector, or would it need to be used within Visual Studio?

I've been running it with the following command:

"IntelliTraceSC.exe" launch /cp:"{pathToCollectionPlan}\collection_plan.ASP.NET.default.xml" /f:"IntellitraceLogs\Test.itrace" "{pathToExecutable}"